# Background process in ruby script with heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, process, background, eventmachine

I want to get info from twitter for my project, I'm using **tweetstream** gem, and it works in my code, but I need it to be done as a background process in `heroku` as a script. So I'm using Event Machine gem to do so, and it works in my computer, but I haven't been able to make it run on heroku on it's own.

I've read that I need to use the Procfile and say it is a worker process, but I can't make it work, but on my local it works fine.

I'm new to background process and working with servers.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos do not support background processes in the "free" or "hobbyist" tiers.

Here is the [Heroku Documentation on Background Jobs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

It costs about $30 bucks a month to add this on. There is other implementation hurdles to overcome with a local server vs. Heroku with background jobs. The best starting point I can give you is that Heroku does not support background jobs by default. You have to "Scale the worker dynos"